# Spring Boot REST mapping conflict event in different controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have two Rest controllers in my Spring boot(1.4.0 RELEASE) app:

```
@RestController("/ctrl")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public void test() {

    }
}


@RestController("/ctrl2")
public class TestController2 {
    @GetMapping
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

When I run the Spring boot app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/ctrl2' method 
public void com.xxx.controller.TestController2.test()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already '/ctrl' bean method
public void com.xxx.controller.TestController.test() mapped.
```

If I delete one controller, everything will be fine and the app can start well. So where is the problem?

Comment: @Veeram still not work even when changing to a quite different path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is change your code like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ctrl")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public void test() {

    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ctrl2")
public class TestController2 {
    @GetMapping
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

Notice that I have added the `RequestMapping` annotation to the controllers.

The name you where using in the  `@RestController` annotation does not have to do with mapping. It's used as the name of the bean that will be registered in the Spring context

Comment: Thank you so much, I was thinking `@RestController` value and `@RequestMapping` value are the same, but they are quite different thing!

Comment: @July That is a common misunderstanding! It's very easy to get mixed up

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the [JavaDoc for `@RestController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html):

> **value**
>   The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

So you have declated a controller bean named `/ctrl` and another named `/ctrl2`, both mapped to `/`!

Did you perhaps mean:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ctrl")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

From the [JavaDoc for `@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

> **value**
>   **Supported at the type level as well as at the method level!** When used at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this primary mapping, narrowing it for a specific handler method.
>   <sub>emphasis theirs</sub>